# Can Dispel Magic remove Blindness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

Can *Dispel Magic* remove blindness, per the spell *Blindness/Deafness*.  I thought it should be harder than just a straight dispel check, but since *Blindness* is a "permanent" duration spell, it should work.

<sub>Is this just 3.5 confusion on my part?</sub>

Comment: A seriously debilitating, permanent, level 2 spell that couldn't be dispelled would feel insanely overpowered to me.

Comment: @Coreworlder A lot of spells have (or had in 3.5) could only be dispelled by certain spells.  There is also *Remove Blindness/Deafness* that is a 3rd level spell (same as *Dispel Magic*).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Yes, at least for blindness caused by *Blindness/Deafness***

*[Blindness/Deafness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blindness-deafness)* has the following duration:

> **Duration** permanent (D)

Checking the duration against [the rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Duration):

> **Permanent**
>
> The energy remains as long as the effect does. *This means the spell is vulnerable to dispel magic.*

(emphasis added)

It's also worth noting that *Blindness / Deafness* is self-dismissible:

> **(D) Dismissible**
>
> If the duration line ends with “(D),” you can dismiss the spell at will.

Finally, *[Dispel Magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic)* has two caveats:

> Some spells, as detailed in their descriptions, can't be defeated by dispel magic.
>
> [...]
>
> The effect of a spell with an instantaneous duration can't be dispelled, because the magical effect is already over before the dispel magic can take effect.

*Blindness/Deafness* is neither Instantaneous in duration, nor does it explicitly state that it can't be dispelled. Therefore it's fair game.

Note that some causes of blindness *can't* be cured by *Dispel Magic*. *[Blinding Critical](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/blinding-critical-combat-critical)* was the first such ability I came across in a quick search of the SRD. Blindness like this (not caused by a spell) as well as most natural blindness must be cured via *[Remove Blindness/Deafness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-blindness-deafness)*.

Answer (score 10):

@AceCalhoon's answer is excellent, but I just wanted to add a little extra:  *Remove Blindness-Deafness* might at first seem like a subset of *Dispel Magic*, but it's important to note that *Dispel Magic* can only dispel magically-induced blindness/deafness conditions, in addition to other magical effects, while *Remove Blindness-Deafness* can only cure those conditions, but works regardless of its origins. When the condition is magically-induced, then they happen to have the same effect.

Comment: Also note that Dispel Magic requires a dispel check, and Remove Blindness/Deafness does not.

Answer (score 1):

Additional Curse info [from PZO1135](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation):

> Many spells can place curses on unfortunate victims. Their effects are usually simple and can be ended with the right spell (but never dispel magic).

Seems Dispel Magic is specifically called out as **not** affecting **curses**.

Comment: But is the spell *blindness/deafness* a curse?

Comment: Yes, it's right in the spell description.

Answer (score -2):

From the dispel magic description, "A dispelled spell ends as if its duration had expired:. Since it has a duration of permanent there is no expiration of it's effect and dispel magic would not work.

Comment: This seems to contradict the top/accepted answer by @AceCalhoon. Could you explain why your interpretation of the rules is better? His seems better researched/sourced and compelling.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. On Magic on [Duration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Duration) on Permanent says, "The energy remains as long as the effect does. This means the spell is vulnerable to *dispel magic*." However, if this answer wants to make the case that *dispel magic*'s specificity overrules the general Magic section, that's certainly one way to roll! No matter what though—sincerely!—, thank you for for participating and for trying to help strangers!